# JPanel won't move if it fills the screen

Tags: java, swing, animation, jpanel

First of all, sorry for the vague title I don't know how to word the question in a sentence.

I have a simple programme that slides one JPanel into view as another gets pushed out, when a button is clicked.

If the first JPanel's width is set as `getWidth()` then the JPanel will not move when the button is clicked, however if I change the width to `getWidth() - 1` it works perfectly fine!?!

A simple example is shown below

```
public class SlidingJPanel extends JFrame{

    public JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    public JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
    public JLabel label = new JLabel(" SUCCESS!!!!!!!");
    public JButton button = new JButton("TESTING"); 

    public class MyJPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
        public int x = 0;
        public int delay = 70;
        final Timer timer = new Timer(delay,this);

        public MyJPanel(){};

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
        {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            button.setBounds(10, 20, 100, 50);
            button.addActionListener(this);
            panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
            panel.setBounds(x, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            panel.add(button);
            panel2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.blue));
            panel2.setBounds(x - getWidth(), 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            panel2.add(label);
            add(panel);
            add(panel2);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            timer.addActionListener(move);
            timer.start();
        }

        ActionListener move = new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                repaint();
                x++;
            }
        };

    }

    public static void main(String args [])
    {         
        new SlidingJPanel();        
    }

    SlidingJPanel()
    {
        Container container = getContentPane();
        MyJPanel panel = new MyJPanel();
        container.add(panel);           
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(500,500);
        setTitle("JPanel Draw Rect Animation");
        setVisible(true);
    }       
}
```

ignore any coding conventions I may have ignored or missed this is just a rough draft.

Hope someone can help :)

Comment: Stop using Absolute Positioning, instead the answer to your question lies in using [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

Comment: but can you animated transitions with a CardLayout? I was under the impression it just instantly switches the JPanel.

Comment: Yeah, that's true, instantly is what you get with `CardLayout`. You can try [Component.setLocation()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setLocation(int,%20int)) as suggested by camickr in the answer, simply inside the `actionPerformed()` method of the `Timer`

Comment: Please do add, `secondPanel.revalidate();`, inside `timerAction`'s `actionPerformed()` method before `if-else` block. I guess that's my mistake, forgot to add that inside the code. For the rest you're MOST WELCOME and KEEP SMILING :-)

Comment: One very good link regarding [Sliding Layout](https://github.com/AurelienRibon/sliding-layout), thought you might be interested :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The paintComponent() method is for painting only! There is no need for you to override this method.

You should NOT be:

1. updating the property of components (ie. bounds, border)
2. adding components to a container

If you want to animate a component then when the timer fires you can use setLocation(...) or setSize() or setBounds(). The component will automatically be repainted.

I don't know if fixing this will solve your problem, but the current approach is wrong.

Comment: Thanks so much for explaining the correct way of implement the animation. It has allowed it to work even when filling the screen.

I'm still not sure why it doesn't work in `paintComponent()` but I shouldn't be doing that anyway so it doesn't matter.